# CSS3 transition not working as expected on expanding

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am able to use Css3 transition while shrinking a bootstrap Navbar at following example but in scrolling down (re-expanding) the height of navbar is not taking care of the transition and just jumps to `min-height: 80px;` from `min-height: 60px;`

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.navbar {
    min-height: 80px;
    transition: min-height 0.5s linear;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    transition: height 0.5s linear;
    transition: line-height 0.5s linear;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 80px;
    transition: line-height .5s linear;
}
.affix {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 60px;
    transition: min-height 0.5s linear;
}

.affix .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

}
.affix .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 60px;
   
}
.container1 {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (or more) of the properties that changes is missing in your `transition`.

In below sample I changed it to `all` to show how that looks, though I recommend you write up each property instead, like this:

```
transition: height 0.5s linear, line-height 0.5s linear;
```

If you do like this, the last overwrite the first

```
transition: height 0.5s linear;
transition: line-height 0.5s linear;
```

```css
.navbar {
    min-height: 80px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 80px;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
.affix {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 60px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.affix .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

}
.affix .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 60px;
   
}
.container1 {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container1"></div>
```